# Get substring excerpt based on search input

Tags: php, mysql

I have the task to create an excerpt of a string based on the first match of user given search input and highlight the first result.

I have figured out the following solution:

```
function substrExcerpt($search, $text): string
{
    $pos = mb_stripos($text, $search);

    if ($pos === false) {
        $pos = 0;
    }

    $searchLength = mb_strlen($search);
    $textLength = mb_strlen($text);

    if ($textLength < $searchLength + 200) {
        $excerpt = $text;
    } else {
        $prefix = $pos > 100 ? '...' : '';
        $suffix = $pos < $textLength - 100 - $searchLength ? '...' : '';

        $excerpt = $prefix . mb_substr($text, $pos - 100 > 0 ? $pos - 100 : 0, $searchLength + 200) . $suffix;
    }

    return highlightSearchTextString($search, $excerpt);
}

function highlightSearchTextString($search, $string) {
    return preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote(e($search)) . ')/i', '<b>$1</b>', e($string));
}
```

As there will be thousands of entries that have to be processed in one request cycle,
I have the feeling that this task could be done in a better and more optimized way. Maybe it could be handled on mysql level, or with built in functions.

Anyone having a suggestion how this could be improved performance wise or logic wise? Maybe there are existing solutions I simply did not find?

The input text for this functions simply comes from an SQL text column entry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would better be asked on CodeReview

Comment: I actually think your solution isn't too bad. It uses only lowlevel php functions, which are already pretty much optimized. So my question would be: before you start optimizing stuff that you don't need to, do you have any performance issues? Because this seems pretty good for an average php application. If you are really worried, just run your function 1000 times with a for loop and let's see what the execution time is.

Comment: You may want to investigate [FULLTEXT search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html), a feature of MySQL that searches for words.  That will help with your needle-in-the-haystack problem searching many values of `$text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the slowest function in your code is `mb_stripos`. This function uses a very slow search algorithm, because of the multibytes (and also case-insensitivity has a slight performance impact). `mb_strlen` also has a slight performance impact.

I've tested below code:

```php
<?php
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis tristique arcu, ac molestie neque. Quisque at ex nulla. Fusce tincidunt posuere urna, vitae molestie mauris. Ut ornare odio uis...';

function search($search, $text): void
{
    $searchLength = mb_strlen($search);
    for ($x=0; $x < 10000; $x++) {
        substrExcerpt('tristique', $text, $searchLength);
    }
}

function substrExcerpt($search, $text, $searchLength): string
{
    $textLength = mb_strlen($text);
    if ($textLength < $searchLength + 200) {
        return highlightSearchTextString($search, $text);
    }

//    $pos = mb_stripos($text, $search);
//    $pos = stripos($text, $search);
    $pos = strpos($text, $search);
    if ($pos === false) {
        $pos = 0;
    }

    $prefix = $pos > 100 ? '...' : '';
    $suffix = $pos < $textLength - 100 - $searchLength ? '...' : '';
    $excerpt = $prefix . mb_substr($text, $pos - 100 > 0 ? $pos - 100 : 0, $searchLength + 200) . $suffix;

    return highlightSearchTextString($search, $excerpt);
}

function highlightSearchTextString($search, $string) {
   return preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($search) . ')/i', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
}

search('tristique', $text);
```

Benchmark outcome:

```sh
➜ time php tmp.php // with mb_stripos()
php tmp.php  0.51s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.527 total
➜  time php tmp.php // with stripos()
php tmp.php  0.22s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 0.233 total
➜  time php tmp.php // with strpos()
php tmp.php  0.15s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 0.169 total
```

So, ask yourself if you:

1. really need the multibyte search functions
2. really need to transform 10.000 records (a user will never read thousands of records. are you only showing 100? then you should only search-replace those 100)

Again, try to avoid premature optimization, first make sure you know which requirements you have for this usecase. If you are only gonna show 100 records each time, your code performs pretty good, so no worries there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the multibyte versions as we are in Germany and without multibyte it does not work correctly with umlauts. The results are part of a lexicon that is likely to get entries in count of more than a million in the next years. The results are displayed within datatables, and should be searchable inside it. So yes, there could be serveral thousands entries displayed inside one page. An alternative would be to load datatables data via ajax search, but that would be incredibly hard to provide the search functionality within the actual displayed excerpts...

Comment: Hmm.. ok, then I think you should look into using something like ElasticSearch, as it is developed exactly for these kinds of purposes. It has multiple lexers, indexation mechanisms and powerful fulltext search. You could use this official library: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I think I will leave it as it is for now and have a look at Elastic Search when time comes. Never thought about that approach.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could only return records that contain your search string:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%$search%'"
```

Remember to sanitize your search string.

Comment: This is the way I already search with mysql. But this returns the whole text column input. I have to manipulate it in a way, that only the excerpt is shown.